# Pipe request, resend request to another endpoint (make a common endpoint that lead to another endpoint

Tags: api, http, routes, api-design, fastapi

I want to create a common `/me` endpoint for all my roles (operators, managers, simple users, etc.) for all 4 methods, `GET, POST, DELETE, UPDATE`.

I found 2 methods to do it:

1. Call correspond function inside endpoint (requires to create a separate endpoint for every HTTP method).
2. Redirection (Allow to create a single function).

That is how it looks:

```python
@router.get(path="/me", status_code=200)  # Var 1
async def get_my_profile(
        token: str = Depends(config.oauth2_scheme),
        postgres_session: AsyncSession = Depends(database.get_db), ):
    try:
        token_payload = jose_jwt.get_unverified_claims(token=token)
        if token_payload['role'] == config.USER_ROLE:
            return await routers.users.get_user(user_id=int(token_payload['sub']),
                                                token=token,
                                                postgres_session=postgres_session)
    except Exception as error:
        services.error_handler(error)
   

@router.api_router(path="/me", status_code=200, methods=["GET", "POST", "DELETE", "PATCH"])  # Var 2
async def get_my_profile(request: Request, token: str = Depends(config.oauth2_scheme),):
    try:
        token_payload = services.get_token_payload(token=token)
        scheme_ip_port = f'{request.url.scheme}://{request.url.hostname}:{request.url.port}'
        urls = [f"{scheme_ip_port}/users/{token_payload['sub']}",
                f"{scheme_ip_port}/operators/{token_payload['sub']}",
                f"{scheme_ip_port}/clinics/employees/{token_payload['sub']}",
                ]
        for i, url in enumerate(iterable=urls):
            if i == token_payload['role']:
                return responses.RedirectResponse(url=url)
    except Exception as error:
        services.error_handler(error)
```

Which one is preferred to use? What drawbacks every solution has?

Comment: Boils down to a matter of taste. Redirection may be the simplest in terms of expansion and maintenance as you add parameters to your base user endpoint, new nested endpoints, etc. Also, if the behavior and results are expected to be _very_ different relative to role, is there really a good reason to implement a `/me` route at all ?

Comment: @michaeldel Yeap, let's make life easier for users:)